# L sets and Probability theory

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, expected-value, subset

I am required to prove the following:

Let $L_1$ be the space of real-valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},\mathbb{P})$ which have finite expectation $\mathbb{E}(|X|)<\infty$ and let $L_2$ be the space of real-valued random variables such that $\mathbb{E}(X^2)<\infty$. Show that $L_2 \subset L_1$.

Thus far, I have that $E|X|$=$E|X|_{I|X|<1}$+$E|X|_{I|X|≥1}$ ≤$E1$+$EX^2_{I|X|≥1}$ ≤ 1+$EX^2$<∞

I have used the fact that |X|≤$X^2$ when |X|≥1.

Comment: Self-study question require you to show us what have you done so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: What you have is correct. Note that the inclusion $L_2\subset L_1$ is not true for general measure spaces where the space may have infinite measure.